# Android onClick() assistance with method call

Tags: android

I have a method which is called when the user hits my create button, this calls a method names createEntry();

within this method it goes through several checks and returns toasts or errors depending on the outcome, when it runs the correct outcome it always takes me back to my home activity but i want it to stay on the current screen if there is an error, how can i do this?

Can anyone give me some assistance with this please

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.create_button:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Home.class);
                    createEntry();// this is where my error checking is done so what I would like to know is how can i stay on the current screen for certain errors
        startActivity(i);
        break;
}
}

    }
```

i don't want to load the home class if there is an error i want it to stay on the current screen.

Comment: Please post the relevant code and any logcat errors. Without an example we have no idea what "stay on the current screen" means; activity, dialog, viewflipper, etc...

Comment: there's no error, what I am saying is once the buttons click how can i stay on the current screen if there is an error rather go to my home screen posted my onClick above

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you should return a boolean about whether you have errors to fix:

```
if(createEntry() == true) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `createEntry()` should return a boolean which repesents if an error occurred or not. With that you can indicate if you should start the new activity or not.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.create_button:
            if (createEntry()) { // return true for no errors
                Intent i = new Intent(this, Home.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for errors and then return from the method if any are found:

```
if (!createEntry()) return;
```